# Exclamation mark over messages icon

Tags: messages

I have an exclamation mark showing over my messages icon on my iPhone and it wont let me access messages. Any idea how to resolve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exclamation mark means that a message you attempted to send was not sent—you had no signal, for example.